# How to avoid unwanted exception information when using SkipException?

Tags: selenium, exception, testng

I am trying to learn about skipping a test in TestNG by throwing SkipException as it helps you skip the tests which are not ready. But the exception information being displayed is messing up the report. Is there any way to avoid that?
The code is:

```
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SkipTest  {
@Test(expectedExceptions = SkipException.class)
public void skip() throws Exception{
throw new SkipException("Skipping");
System.out.println("skip executed");
}
```

Excepting the exception and throwing it in the method declaring are not helping.

Comment: Putting the exception in a conditional statement and the remaining code in the alternate logic for the condition solves the problem of showing messy exception information in the report.

Comment: if(str.equals(expectedString))
    throw new SkipException("Skipping");
   else
    System.out.println("code goes here");

Comment: Here, "System.out.println("code goes here"); " is not unreachable. So no exception information is getting displayed when I run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to mark a `@Test` method as skipped, and still would not like to see the exception information in the reports, then you should not be throwing the `TestSkipException`.

Here's how you do this (You would need to leverage TestNG listeners)

The test class looks like below

```java
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(SkipMarker.class)
public class SampleTestClass {

  @Test
  public void passMethod() {}

  @Test
  public void skipMethod() {
    // Adding an attribute to the current Test Method's result object to signal to the
    // TestNG listener (SkipMarker), that this method needs to be marked as skipped.
    Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setAttribute("shouldfail", true);
  }
}
```

Here's how the TestNG listener looks like

```java
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class SkipMarker implements IInvokedMethodListener {

  @Override
  public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {}

  @Override
  public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    // Look for the signalling attribute from the test method's result object
    Object value = testResult.getAttribute("shouldfail");
    if (value == null) {
      // If the attribute was not found, dont proceed further.
      return;
    }
    // attribute was found. So override the test status to failure.
    testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println("skip executed");` was unreachable, if you fix your test as below there's no exception information being displayed

```
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SkipTest  {
   @Test(expectedExceptions = SkipException.class)
   public void skip() {
      throw new SkipException("Skipping");    
   }
}
```

Comment: Suppose that I want to skip the test execution when the test data is not available. So the condition of checking whether the test data is available or not will be at the first of the method definition. What's the solution then? I can't check the condition at the end of the method definition, right?

Comment: @learningQA add relevant condition before throwing the exception, for a more specific answer ask a more specific question

Comment: Yeah. I can add the condition before throwing the exception. But the below code will still be unreachable, right?

Comment: @learningQA throwing exception stop execution of code, if you want you can move `System.out.println` **before** throwing exception

Comment: Using test data before checking its availability will result in an error. I do not want the test to be marked as FAILED.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Comment: @user7294900 - The sample that you shared I guess causes the test to pass because the expected exception was fulfilled. I guess the question from OP was around, I would like to skip a test, but I would not like to see the exception stacktrace etc., on the reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to skip tests that are not ready, use [@Test(enabled=false) annotation](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng).